# Is there a way to call method with base class pointer that uses the data in derived class?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, base-class

(sorry for my bad english)

I have a base class with vector of pointers on Drawable objects in it and method draw() that uses data from this vector.

```
class GameObject
{
protected:
    std::vector<Drawable*> drawable;
...

void GameObject::draw() { for (const auto& object : drawable) window.draw(*object); }
```

In the derived classes I want to have an ability to add some Drawable objects

```
class Player : public GameObject
{
protected:
    RectangleShape shape;
...

Player::Player(float x, float y, float z)
{
    shape.setPosition [...]
    drawable.push_back(&shape);
...
```

and draw them using method of base class pointer

```
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
...
for (auto& gameObject : gameObjects) gameObject->draw();
```

The program crashes (I think because the base class don't know anything about vector data in derived class).
I understand that I could make this method pure virtual and define it in the derived classes, but it's not that convenient. Maybe there is another way more similar to this?

upd:

```
Level::Level()
{
    player = Player(500.f, 500.f); //Player player; in header file
    gameObjects.push_back(&player);
}

void Level::display()
{
    for (auto gameObject : gameObjects) gameObject->draw();
}
```

Comment: "*The program crashes (I think because the base class don't know anything about vector data in derived class)*" - that is not the problem. The code looks fine to me, so it is likely crashing elsewhere in the code you have not shown. For example, if the `GameObject*` pointers in `gameObjects` are pointing at invalid objects. You did not show how `gameObjects` is populated.

Comment: What you have shown so far would work fine.  However, if you ever make a copy of a `Player` object, the `Player::GameObject::drawable` vector in the new copy still holds the address of the `Player::shape` in the old copy, leading to trouble.  So make sure to disable copying and moving of an object doing this.

Comment: @BenVoigt or, simply implement copy/move constructors in `Player` to add the new `shape` into the `drawable` vector rather than the old `shape`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That doesn't seem "simple" if there may be items added to the `drawable` vector at multiple levels of the hierarchy, some of which may need to be deep copied, some translated to a new subobject address, and some left alone (perhaps they refer to globals).  Yes, it's possible to write a copy and move constructor, if those operations are needed.  Most likely they aren't, and are being invoked by accident, which deleting the constructor will reveal.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the code added by your edit -- it looks like my crystal ball is working today.

You're creating a temporary `Player` and moving it into the `player` member variable.  That ends up with a vector holding the address of the `shape` inside the temporary `Player`, which is immediately destroyed, leaving a dangling pointer.

Use a *ctor-initializer-list* to avoid the move:

```
Level::Level()
    : player(500.f, 500.f /* where did Z go? */)
{
    gameObjects.push_back(&player);
}
```

And disable the assignment operators to prevent doing this by accident in other places:

```
class Player
{
    // ...

    Player& operator=(const Player&) = delete;
    Player& operator=(Player&&) = delete;
};
```